# How to hide contents with the same class name but different id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show-hide

Hi i have to hide contents of tab using submit button. I try to hide the contents but its not working.Even when i try to hide the contents through id the tab itself getting hide. I have same class name with different id's. So in this case how can i hide the contents using class name with their id ? Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
function hide_visibility(classname) { $(classname).hide(); }




$('#news .butt-rahmen').on('click', function(){
            if($(this).attr('id') == 'saveId')                  

                hide_visibility('#news .cont-liste-verlauf');
                getNewsWidgetEdit();


    });
```

Comment: Remove the `.` from `$("."+classname).hide();` and change `live` to `on`. `live` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The '.' is not necessary.  Additionally, I'm assuming you forgot brackets around your `if`

```
function hide_visibility(selector) { $(selector).hide(); }

$('#news .butt-rahmen').live('click', function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'saveId') {
        hide_visibility('#news .cont-liste-verlauf');
        getNewsWidgetEdit();
    }
});
```

That being said, `live` is deprecated, so you should use `on`.  If you need to dynamically attach to `.butt-rahman` classed items under `#news`:

```
function hide_visibility(selector) { $(selector).hide(); }

$(document).on('click', '#news .butt-rahmen', function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'saveId') {
        hide_visibility('#news .cont-liste-verlauf');
        getNewsWidgetEdit();
    }
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated.

Comment: no i tried removing . but still not working and i also use on instead of live but still not working..Please check the updated question..

Comment: Have you debugged your code in the browser?  Does `$('#news .cont-liste-verlauf')` actually select anything?  is `$(this).attr('id')` ever 'saveId'?

Comment: yes i debug my code my button is working fine the problem is i have many classes with the same name but different id's, so i have to take class name with their id to hide the content...